# Numpy reshape preserving some dimensions

Tags: python, numpy, reshape

I want this

```
# assume each 2x2 as assigned number on right

[[[False  True]            # 1  
  [False False]]

 [[False False]            # 2
  [False  True]]

 [[ True False]            # 3
  [False False]]

 [[False  True]            # 4
  [False False]]]
```

to be reshape into

```
[[[[False  True False False]
   [False False False  True]
   [ True False False  True]
   [False False False False]]]]
```

as in

```
[[[[False  True | False False]                # 1 | 2
   [False False | False  True]                ___   ___
     ----------   -----------                  
   [ True False | False  True]                # 3 | 4
   [False False | False False]]]]
```

but I get when using `arr.reshape(1,1,4,4)`

```
[[[[False  True False False]                   # 1 flat
   [False False False  True]                   # 2 flat
   [ True False False False]                   # 3 flat
   [False  True False False]]]]                # 4 flat
```

Notice that each 2x2 is flattened. I want numpy to reshape such that 2x2 remains the same while the dimensions before that are adjusted. How do I do it?

---

*EDIT:* shape of `arr` is `m,n,r` and `m` could be odd

*EDIT2:*

Case 9x2x2 into 1x1x6x6

What I have:

```
[[[False False]
  [False  True]]

 [[False False]
  [False  True]]

 [[ True False]
  [False False]]

 [[False False]
  [False  True]]

 [[False False]
  [ True False]]

 [[False False]
  [ True False]]

 [[False  True]
  [False False]]

 [[False False]
  [ True False]]

 [[ True False]
  [False False]]]
```

Expected:

```
[[[[False False | False False |  True False]
   [False  True | False  True | False False]
    -----------   -----------   ----------
   [False False | False False | False False]
   [False  True |  True False |  True False]
     ----------   -----------   -----------
   [False  True | False False |  True False]
   [False False |  True False | False False]]]]
```

What I got:

```
[[[[False False False  True False False]          # 1 flattened; half of 2
   [False  True  True False False False]          # rem half of 2; flattened 3
   [False False False  True False  True]          # ...
   [False False False  True False False]
   [False False  True False False  True]
   [False False  True False False False]]]]
```

Comment: With an initial (4,2,2) shape, and just `True/False` values it's a little hard to tell how you want to reshape things.  Starting with different sizes in each dimension, e.g. (4,2,3) and different values (e.g. numbers) makes the mapping more obvious and unique.

Comment: hpaulj, updated :) hope its clear now

Comment: So, how can you have number of rows not a multiple of 2 given that way of partitioning?

Comment: updated the ques

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The important piece of the *puzzle* was that the first axis is a square number and we are splitting it by that square-root number, giving us a `4D` array. If the first axis isn't a squared number, we would need another input argument telling us the number of blocks to be kept along the columns or rows in the final output. After splitting, swap axes `1` and `2` and finally reshape -

```
m = int(np.rint(np.sqrt(a.shape[0])))
out = a.reshape(m,m,2,2).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(m*2,-1)
```

Sample run -

1] Input :

```
In [69]: a
Out[69]: 
array([[[False, False],
        [False,  True]],

       [[False, False],
        [False,  True]],

       [[ True, False],
        [False, False]],

       [[False, False],
        [False,  True]],

       [[False, False],
        [ True, False]],

       [[False, False],
        [ True, False]],

       [[False,  True],
        [False, False]],

       [[False, False],
        [ True, False]],

       [[ True, False],
        [False, False]]], dtype=bool)
```

2] Output :

```
In [70]: m = int(np.sqrt(a.shape[0]))

In [71]: a.reshape(m,m,2,2).swapaxes(1,2).reshape(m*2,-1)
Out[71]: 
array([[False, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

Comment: Only the last two dimensions (2,2) are known. how do i come up with `reshape(?,?,2,2)` as I can use only one -1? In fact arr is initially only 3 dimensional :/

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran Updated post.

Comment: i thought of (-1,2,n,r) too, but it doesn't work for odd numbers. For eg: 9x2x2 would refuse to split into (-1, 2, 2, 2). If I try (-1,1,n,r) I'm reshaping the last dim ://

Comment: @SaravanabalagiRamachandran Add such a case and the expected output in the question?

Comment: that technically answers what I need :) I just need to add a couple of ifs to find if it is even or not, or find a another hack that does the same :)

Comment: if odd do (-1,3,n,r); if not (-1,2,n,r); and it works :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `einops` for such cases.

```
In: x

array([[[False, False],
        [False,  True]],

       [[False, False],
        [False,  True]],

       [[ True, False],
        [False, False]],

       [[False, False],
        [False,  True]],

       [[False, False],
        [ True, False]],

       [[False, False],
        [ True, False]],

       [[False,  True],
        [False, False]],

       [[False, False],
        [ True, False]],

       [[ True, False],
        [False, False]]])

In: einops.rearrange(x, '(h w) h2 w2 -> (h h2) (w w2)', h=3)

array([[False, False, False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False, False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True, False, False, False]])
```

See `einops` docs, basically it allows all kinds of rearrangements being written in explicit way.